# Descriptions on pictures using core ML

Tags: swift, xcode, coreml, turi-create

I have made an app with swift and Core ML using Turi Create and it says yes or no but i can't get it to add different descriptions to the pictures when you take a picture  would this work in Core ML or Apple AR kit

[image]

Comment: Hi MeiTheF1x3r, please edit your post to include your code or other relevant information so we can help you debug. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to detect multiple objects along with their locations to use them in ARKit.

In that case, *classifier* is not the right tool for the job. You will need to train and use *object detector*.

Fortunately, Turi Create supports it as well - https://github.com/apple/turicreate/tree/master/userguide/object_detection